# Where is an error in this PHP code?

Tags: php, pdf, composer-php, fatal-error

I have  PHP code that convert PDF files  to text files.For this task I  installed an external library using the composer in order to be able to use the library of the PDF.

The problem is that even when I required the installed library the system still not recognize the **PDF Class**.

The path of the library :

**C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\spatie\pdf-to-text\src\pdf.php**

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Pdf' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\testwebsite\OSWebProject\test2.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\testwebsite\OSWebProject\test2.php on line 5

## code : pdf class

```
<?php

namespace Spatie\PdfToText;

use Spatie\PdfToText\Exceptions\CouldNotExtractText;
use Spatie\PdfToText\Exceptions\PdfNotFound;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

class Pdf
{
    protected $pdf;

    protected $binPath;

    public function __construct(string $binPath = null)
    {
        $this->binPath = $binPath ?? '/usr/bin/pdftotext';
    }

    public function setPdf(string $pdf) : Pdf
    {
        if (!file_exists($pdf)) {
            throw new PdfNotFound("could not find pdf {$pdf}");
        }

        $this->pdf = $pdf;

        return $this;
    }

    public function text() : string
    {
        $process = new Process("{$this->binPath} " . escapeshellarg($this->pdf) . " -");
        $process->run();

        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new CouldNotExtractText($process);
        }

        return trim($process->getOutput(), " \t\n\r\0\x0B\x0C");
    }

    public static function getText(string $pdf, string $binPath = null) : string
    {
        return (new static($binPath))
            ->setPdf($pdf)
            ->text();
    }
}
```

## code:

```
<?php

require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\spatie\pdf-to-text\src\pdf.php');

$text = (new Pdf())
    ->setPdf('اجواء.pdf')
    ->text();
?>
```

Comment: `pdf.php` has `class Pdf` in it? Is it namespaced?

Comment: Don't post a new question just because you didn't get an answer the first time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to includes external libraries on PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639615/how-to-includes-external-libraries-on-php)

Comment: @PatrickQ That question is already a dupe of this one

Comment: @Machavity It wasn't when I cast my vote.  IMO, it doesn't make much sense to mark that one as the dupe when all the relevant info already exists on the other question.

Comment: @PatrickQ but still in both asked questions did not get the answer on what is the error and how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Per [the docs and source](https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text), the `Pdf` class is within the `Spatie\PdfToText` namespace.

You'll need `use Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf;` at the top of your PHP file, or you can reference it as `new Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf()` when you call it.

Comment: You should, however, start using Composer instead of the way you're doing things currently. With more complex libraries, the simple `require_once` approach won't work.

Comment: what u mean start using composer i did use it in order to download the package

Comment: You used Composer to install, but you're not using Composer's built-in autoloader to load classes. You are likely to run into problems because of this. Replacing your `require_once` line with `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` ([as per the Composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)) will let Composer handle loading the necessary classes for your libraries.

Comment: i tried your answer but it display more errors 

`
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\testwebsite\OSWebProjectC:/xampp/htdocs/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\testwebsite\OSWebProject\test2.php on line 3

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\testwebsite\OSWebProjectC:/xampp/htdocs/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\testwebsite\OSWebProject\test2.php on line 3
`

Comment: Then you have the wrong path to your Composer atoloder.