# Class 'Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf' not found

Tags: php, laravel, pdftotext

I tried to keep running Spatie\PdfToText.
I have the following error:

> Class 'Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf' not found

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47641523/where-is-an-error-in-this-php-code) but it doesn't help.

```
use Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf;

public function importInRequestStore($projectId, Request $request)
{
    require  base_path().'/vendor/autoload.php';
    $text = (new Pdf())
        ->setPdf('book.pdf')
        ->text();
}
```

What is wrong in this code? I do not find a solution with google.Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Did you updated autoload after requiring `spatie`?

Comment: yes I did composer update

Comment: i tried to change namespace but still the same error. It's strange!

Comment: Do you have an autoload or a require above this? The `use` statement alone will not load the class file

Comment: I put for all files a require above and it works. but i do not understand, why laravel loads all other files but no this one.

Comment: Have you tried `composer du` or `composer dump-autoload` after adding/changing classes?

Comment: Yes i did. I added some other features by composer and these are working without any problems.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It will not load the class since these spatie classes have no service providers.

You should modify the composer.json which under the root of your Laravel/Lumen project.

You can add a classmap path like below in the autoload node:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "vendor/spatie"
    ]
},
```

Or you can add a psr-4 key-value like below in the autoload node (this is the way recommanded):

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": [
        "Spatie\\": "vendor/spatie"
    ]
},
```

And the last **IMPORTANT** thing is you should `composer dump-autoload` then. Otherwise the spatie class never load in.

Comment: This is not right
It is not Laravel that is responsible for loading packages on vendor folder but composer and if the package is installed via composer max you need is to do a composer dump-autoload.

Answer (score -1):

You must include "autoload.php" as explained here:
https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text/issues/3

So the correct working example in most cases is this:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf;
echo Pdf::getText('book.pdf');
```

So the problem is that there is missing info on the documentation page: https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text

Comment: The (4 year old) question is tagged laravel, it seems reasonable to assume that the code was part of a Laravel application, which should handle the autoload itself.

Comment: @miken32: Yes, it is reasonable to assume many things which can lead to a dead end. Your assumptions are unfortunately incorrect. I tested this myself.